# Youtube V3 Data API - Channels.list function not fetching all the channels

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get a list of youtube channels under one google account. But the api returns only one channel, although I have two channels inside my google account. Is there a way to get all the channels under one google account ? Is there any suggested workaround to this ? I have seen posts saying this is not possible, is this same now ?

Thanks

const service = google.youtube({ version: 'v3', headers: { Authorization: Bearer ${user.youtubeToken}}});

const result = service.channels.list({part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics', mine: true});

Comment: There is a tracked Google bug for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203851452